# Image doesn't scale correctly

Tags: html, css

When I use a pseudo element with before my logo to make it `vertical-center`. doesn't scale any more, it just slips down out of its parent element in small width.

```
<div id="header">
  <div id="logo">
    <img src="http://abload.de/img/unbenannt-1bmq5b.png" alt=""/>
  </div>
</div>
```

[here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cfL3bey8/)

Comment: Your fiddle works fine. I assume what you mean by scale is to fill all the available space for img tag. in that case use height and width instead of max-height and max-width. The latter just scales down if the content is too large for the container.

Comment: no it doesn't when i make my browser smaller the logo slips down as it does in my project.

Comment: So I can't get the problem, What do you want to achieve? can you elaborate? can you make an image of what is your desired result?

Comment: @Cunning If you remove the before pseudo element in the fiddle you can see what i want. the logo should resize when the browser width gets smaller, like in a responsive website. it works wíthout the pseudo element, but it want the image to be vertical aligned, thats why i inserted the pseudo element.

Comment: @Verdemis see the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have used pseudo element to "`vertical-center`" the logo.
The pseudo element acts as an `inline-block` element. so that by `vertical-align: middle` rule, you can bring the other `inline-block` element (logo) to the middle. it works like a charm

add a negative margin in your case to fit both element in the screen.

```
#header #logo:before {
    margin-left: -4px;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/cfL3bey8/2/)

Comment: Thank you that was the solution. But it is strange, i used this a lot before and i had never this problem. But now i know how to solve it. thank you

Comment: @Verdemis : Read this. Even I faced this strange problem once. https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/